# Getting the average redness of an image from a camera on IOS using Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, camera

We're currently working on an app for both Android and IOS using Xamarin. For this app we need a heartbeat monitor that scans how 'red' your finger is (or rather how the colour fluctuates because of the heart) after putting it on the camera for a while.

In order to do this on iOS, we want to find the average redness of each frame while sampling with the camera. After we have the redness values our algorithm will find the BPM.

Right now we're struggling to get the colour of each pixel from a frame. Obviously when we can get the colour of each pixel we can just average the red component, however getting the colour seems difficult.

This is the code we have right now, though we have tried many options found on different forums (they all look similar).

```
public override void DidOutputSampleBuffer (AVCaptureOutput captureOutput, CMSampleBuffer sampleBuffer, AVCaptureConnection connection)
    {           
        // Grab an image from the buffer
        var image = GetImageFromSampleBuffer (sampleBuffer);

        var resolution = Width * Height;

        Width = (int)image.CGImage.Width;
        Height = (int)image.CGImage.Height;

        int bytesPerPixel = 4;
        int bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * Width;
        int bitsPerComponent = 8;

        var rawData = new byte[bytesPerRow * Height];
        var handle = GCHandle.Alloc (rawData);  

        double red_avg = 0;
        double green_avg = 0;
        double blue_avg = 0;

        try {
            using (var colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB ()) {
                using (var context = new CGBitmapContext (rawData, Width, Height,
                                         bitsPerComponent, 
                                         bytesPerRow, 
                                         colorSpace, 
                                         CGBitmapFlags.PremultipliedLast)) {
                    context.DrawImage (new RectangleF(0, 0, Width, Height), image.CGImage);
                }
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
                for(int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
                {
                    var index = bytesPerRow * y + bytesPerPixel * x;

                    byte red   = rawData[index];
                    byte green = rawData[index + 1];
                    byte blue  = rawData[index + 2];
                    byte alpha = rawData[index + 3];

                    red_avg += red;
                    green_avg += green;
                    blue_avg += blue;
                }

            //Console.WriteLine("V1: " + red_avg / resolution + "  V2: " + blue_avg / resolution + "  V3: " + green_avg / resolution);
        }
        finally {

            handle.Free ();
            sampleBuffer.Dispose ();
        }
    }
```

The above code is run every frame.
When we run our program the average red, green and blue values all roughly become the same value every frame, however they in- and decrement in the way you would expect when exposing the camera to more or less light.

We feel we might not understand fully how we should read the colour values from the byte array we construct.

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot all about this post, I guess since I've found an answer to my question I will add it here as well if anyone ever has need for this very specific problem.

The outputformat of tbe bytearray was different than what we figured it would be (rgba). So all we had to do was change the pixelformat in the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput we used. We set the pixelformat type to CV32BGRA and everything worked after that.